# ResourceBundle Editor does not appear after installation on Eclipse Photon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, resourcebundle

I installed the ResourceBundle Editor 1.0.6 on Eclipse Photon via the Marketplace and restarted Eclipse. But I can't see the Editor anywhere. It's not an option in the settings (as stated on the official homepage) and I can't choose it, when right clicking on the keys in the property files.

Does anyone know how to get it working?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **ResourceBundle Editor** entry on the context menu when you right click a properties file. Instead, do this

1. Select your properties file in **Project Explorer**.
2. Right-click and select **Open With > ResourceBundle Editor**.

   [image: openBundle]

   Alternatively, just double-click the properties file.
3. The **ResourceBundle Editor** window will open.

   [image: ResourceBundle Editor]

If that approach does not work then verify that the plugin was installed successfully (**Help > About Eclipse IDE > Installation Details > Installed Software**), and reinstall **ResourceBundle Editor** if it is not shown.

[image: InstalledSoftware]